# How to get value of input using Jquery and put it in css of an element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a text input where you are suppose to write Hex code of color. Than I need Jquery to get a content of the input and place it to style of div so that it change the background color of the div. Can you guys help me?

```
<form>
  <label>Set color: </label>
  <input type="text" name="set_color" id="color" />
  <div id="color_result"></div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle - My code](https://jsfiddle.net/4jgLkrLo/)

Comment: This seems to be popping up a bit lately...school project? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#color').on('keyup', function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $('#color_result').css('background-color', color);
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably want to let them think a bit before giving them the answer :/

Answer (score 1):

To expand on D4V1D's answer, add some validation in there, like:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#color').on('keyup', function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        if (color.match(/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i) !== null){
            $('#color_result').css('background-color', color);
            $('#validation').text('Good color! Have a biscuit!');

        }else{
            $('#validation').text('Bad Color. No doughnut.');
        }
    });
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/rbvu663h/)